# How to display onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-camera, image-gallery

I am new to android and I have developed one application in which the user can pick the image from camera or gallery to display it on a cover page or profile page based on context menu options.

So how can I show the image based on user selection whether for cover page or profile page?

Here I have tried onActivityResult:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 0:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                imageCoverPage.setImageURI(selectedImage);
            } else {
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                profileImage.setImageURI(selectedImage);
            }
            break;

        case 1:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                imageCoverPage.setImageURI(selectedImage);
            } else {
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                profileImage.setImageURI(selectedImage);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: save the user selection in some variable like int or string and then check for that variables value in onActivityResult()

Comment: Save Uri of selectedImage in variable and show it in `onResume()` method.

Comment: Hi @DennyDog can you please edit it.. as am not able to rectify..thanks in advance

Comment: use [this library](https://github.com/ParkSangGwon/TedBottomPicker) and simply your life

Comment: How exactly is the code you have not working?